# UNCalendarNotificationTrigger with Future Date

Tags: ios, notifications, ios10

Is it possible to give future date for calendar trigger with repeat mode YES. i.e notification should fire from given date to daily (every next day).  For Eg. I want notification everyday at 8AM upto 30 days, but it should fire after 2 days to 30 days but not from today.

```
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitTimeZone
                                           fromDate:fireDate];
UNMutableNotificationContent *objNotificationContent = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
objNotificationContent.title = @"Sample";
UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:components repeats:YES];
```

The `fireDate` is future date, but while using dateComponents with Hour and Minute its firing from today.

Comment: Try making a subclass of `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` and override the `nextTriggerDate` function to pass it 2 days after, instead of 1.

Comment: Instead of Overriding nextTriggerDate is there any way to give future-date as notification start-date for UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.
I am using NSCalendarUnitHour and NSCalendarUnitMinute as NSDateComponents for UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.

Comment: In order for us to help you best you need to test some solutions and show us what is/isn't working. If you have some ideas give them a try and then post it in your question. It's far easier to help when we can see your code.

Comment: NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitSecond|NSCalendarUnitTimeZone fromDate:fireDate];
UNMutableNotificationContent *objNotificationContent = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
objNotificationContent.title = @"Sample";
UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:components repeats:YES];
The fireDate is future date, but while using dateComponents with Hour and Minute its firing from today.

Comment: Haha don't write it in the comments, update your question so that we can see it cleanly formatted :)

Comment: Updated the question, Thx.

Comment: Hello. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @GuyKogus Subclassing UNCalendarNotificationTrigger doesn't fire notification at all.

Comment: Any solution to this very good question that Vinay Kumar Darna asked ??